# Remove columns with -c()

Tags: r

I know that one should be able to delete columns with -c() and the column names. But weirdly it doesn't work in my R. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(4,5,6), x3=c(7,8,9))
df <- df[,-c("x1", "x2")]
```

I tried this and expected it to remove columns x1 and x2 but instead I get this error:

> Error in -c("x1", "x2") : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: I think data frame can be only one column

Comment: You are using data.frame instead of data.table. df <- data.table(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(4,5,6), x3=c(7,8,9))